# How do I set cookies for CloudFront distribution using troposphere?

Tags: cookies, amazon-cloudfront, troposphere

Using troposhphere, I am trying to create CloudFront distribution.

```
CacheBehaviors = [
                CacheBehavior(
                    TargetOriginId = Join("", ["cloudfront-", Ref("ParamOriginName")]),
                    PathPattern = '/en/Login/*',
                    AllowedMethods = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "POST","PATCH"],
                    ForwardedValues = ForwardedValues(
                        QueryString = True,
                        Headers = ["user-agent",
                                "Host",
                                "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto", 
                                "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer", 
                                "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer",
                                "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer",
                                "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer",
                                "CloudFront-Viewer-Country",
                                "Origin",
                                "Referer"]
                        ),
                    MaxTTL = 86400,
                    MinTTL = 14400,
                    DefaultTTL = 43200,
                    ViewerProtocolPolicy = "redirect-to-https",
                    Compress = True,
                ),
```

This seems to build the json template fine. But I also need to forward cookies. After the line `QueryString` I inserted `Cookies = "All"` but this failed the build.

The error message:
`TypeError: <class 'troposphere.cloudfront.ForwardedValues'>: None.Cookies is <class 'str'>, expected <class 'troposphere.cloudfront.Cookies'>`

What do I need to add so that it does not fail the build and forwards cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out after reading this [document](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/troposphere/latest/troposphere.pdf)

After the line `QueryString = True,`
I added

`Cookies = Cookies(Forward = "all"),` 
and it now builds without errors and adds the correct cookies value to the json template